# Finding Correct Graphics Drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics, 18.04

i just switched to Ubuntu 18.04 and i don't have the proper graphics driver and i don't have access to any saturation settings even with ccsm

my screen looks extremely discolored and i don't know what to do because i can't find the software for my driver

i'm using an AMD® A6-7310 apu with amd radeon r4 graphics × 4